# Make downstream task dependent on Branch Operator, but execute anyway if branch condition not satisfied

Tags: airflow

I am trying to execute the following airflow dag:

```
start >> BranchDayOfWeekOperator >> TaskA >> TaskB >> end
```

I want `TaskB` to be dependent on `TaskA` when the branching condition is satisfied. However, when it is not satisfied, execute `TaskB` anyways.

```
start >> TaskB >> end
```

Is this possible?

Comment: in your branchOperator function can you check for some condtion that would be valid for Task A (i.e return 'TaskA' ) then add an elif/ else block to the condition to return 'TaskB' 

i.e have the following order of tasks:

start >> branchtask >> [ taska, taskb ]
taska >> taskb >> end
taskb >> end

Comment: Yes it is possible [Airflow branching](https://vuitton.atlassian.net/browse/DATA-5695)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Simply change the [trigger_rule](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules) for TaskB to `none_failed`. Then, even if upstream tasks are skipped, TaskB will run as long as none of the tasks have explicitly failed.